# How can I make each array multiply by each other in a nested for loop, using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Currently, I'm working on a school project involving buck converters. As current increase through an inductor, its inductance decrease (most likely). Each phase is adding an inductor. By adding an inductor, I divide the current by each added inductor. The current is ramped from 0 to 500.

My issue with the following code is that it does not use each array value of `i_L(i,j)` correctly. I receive some negative values, which is absolutely wrong.

In example...

At 500 Amps with 10 phases, each inductor uses 50 amps. Now `L` will be designed after

```
i_L(i,j)=current(j)./phases(i)= 500/10=50amps

L(i,j)= (-9.22297516731983*10^(-16).*(50^(4)))+(9.96260934359008*10^(-14).*(50^(3)))-(3.6355216850551*10^(-12).*(50^(2)))+(9.0205832462444*10^(-12).*(50^(1)))+1.06054781561763E-07 = 1.04106*10^(-7)
```

and so on

creating 10x10 = 100 cells

```
clc; clear all;
    phases=linspace(1,10,10);
    current=linspace(0,500,10); 

for j = 1:10
    for i=1:10
          i_L(i,j)=current(j)./phases(i);

          L(i,j)=(-0.000000000000000922297516731983*(i_L(i,j).^(4)))+(0.000000000000099626093435900800*(i_L(i,j).^(3)))-(0.000000000003635521685055100000*(i_L(i,j).^(2)))+(0.000000000009020583246244400000*(i_L(i,j).^(1)))+0.000000106054781561763000000000;
    end
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: In MATLAB you can write `-9.22297516731983e-16`. No need to type so many zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix `i_L(i,j)` got values up to 500=500(current)/1(amp).
The polynomial you're using is generating negative solutions for values greater than 130.
So the operation is using each array value correct.
Maybe you should reevaluate the polynomial, if you're dissatisfied with the solution.

Try:

```
x=[0:1:500];
y=(-9.22297516731983*10^(-16).*(x.^(4)))+(9.96260934359008*10^(-14).*(x.^(3)))-(3.6355216850551*10^(-12).*(x.^(2)))+(9.0205832462444*10^(-12).*(x.^(1)))+1.06054781561763E-07;
plot(x,y)
```

You will see the polynomial will diverge against negative infinite for positive values.